# How to input to a variable with an output of a Linux command

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk, yaml

I am trying to send the output of a linux command as an input to variable. Here is the command I tried

```
cat init.txt | grep glal20213lvdlb04
glal13lvd
```

The output of this should go into "vm_name" of the yml file. The yml file will look like this.

```
vim instant.yml
```

```
resources:

  instance01:
    type: ../../../templates/ipnf.yaml
    properties:
      vm_name: 'THE OUTPUT SHOULD COME HERE'
      vm_flavour: 'dsolate'
      image_name: 'pdns_14121207'
      vm_az: 'az-1'
      vm_disk_root_size: '50'
      vm_disk_data_size: '50'
      network_mgmt_refs: 'int:dxs_pcg'
      network_mgmt_ip: '10.194.112.75'
```

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

You can use [yq](/questions/tagged/yq) to replace the YAML.

Use yq's `strenv()` to get a bash env variable.

We can export the desired value using

```
export newValue="$(grep glal20213lvdlb04 init.txt)"
```

And the generate the YAML:

```
 yq e '.resources.instance01.properties.vm_name = strenv(newValue)' instant.yml
```

Ouput:

```yaml
resources:
  instance01:
    type: ../../../templates/ipnf.yaml
    properties:
      vm_name: 'glal20213lvdlb04'
      vm_flavour: 'dsolate'
      image_name: 'pdns_14121207'
      vm_az: 'az-1'
      vm_disk_root_size: '50'
      vm_disk_data_size: '50'
      network_mgmt_refs: 'int:dxs_pcg'
      network_mgmt_ip: '10.194.112.75'
```

Comment: yq is not installed in the server. Any other straight forward method?

Answer (score 1):

While I would recommend a proper YAML processor like `yq`, for your particular situation, you may be able to utilize `sed`:

```
var=$(grep 'glal20213lvdlb04' init.txt) ; sed -i'' -e "s/THE OUTPUT SHOULD COME HERE/${var}/g" instant.yaml
```

Output:

```
resources:

  instance01:
    type: ../../../templates/ipnf.yaml
    properties:
      vm_name: 'glal20213lvdlb04'
      vm_flavour: 'dsolate'
      image_name: 'glal20213lvdlb04'
      vm_az: 'az-1'
      vm_disk_root_size: '50'
      vm_disk_data_size: '50'
      network_mgmt_refs: 'int:dxs_pcg'
      network_mgmt_ip: '10.194.112.75'
```

Comment: This worked. But can "THE OUTPUT SHOULD COME HERE" be auto detected? Like search for vm_name= and replace whatever it is with $var?  @j_b